# Specify the Schema in a HQL query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Please, I would want to know how to specify the schema in a HQL query. 
Let's say I have a HQL query : `FROM Cat where Id = 1`
But the table Cat is in the schema ANIMAL. 
And when I run the query in Eclipse, I get an error message telling that Cat table is not mapped which is completely false. 
I think I have to specify the schema which is Animal in my query. 
But how to do that ?

Comment: You should specify the scmeha in Cat Entity class

Comment: It's already the case. I have : @Entity
@Table(name="Cat"
    ,schema="Animal"
) So, It means that my problem is elsewhere ?

Comment: I doubt it's the schema, the error seems to be thrown by Hibernate, not the DB (in Oracle it would be table or view does not exist)

Comment: Set show_sql to true and run the query to see real SQL fired

Comment: I'm so stupid, my hibernate.cfg.xml file was configured as shit. The class cat was not there for example. It's weird, when I run the hibernate code generation configuration, it did not set correctly the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: So, I have another question : I have more than 4000 classes that are not mapped in hibernate.cfg.xml. How can I set the xml file correctly whitout losing huge amount of time ?

Comment: Maybe you should delete this question, since it is not generally useful. Ask about your 4000 classes in a new question. Nobody will see it here.